# NSCoder - Encoding an Array, with multiple levels of nested arrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, saving-data, nscoder

I have a mainObjectArray (NSMutableArray) which is populated with instances of a custom class. Each instance is itself an array, and objects in each array are NSDates, NSStrings, BOOL, and more arrays containing similar objects.

What I haven't been able to establish is whether it's possible to, inside the

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
```

method, to just say something like that:

```
[encoder encodeWithObject:mainObjectArray];
```

Or do have to encode every object in every instance separately? This would be a bit of a pain...

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "each instance is itself an array"? Do you simply mean that your custom class instances **have** an array property? Or is it a subclass of `NSArray`?

Comment: Sorry for being inaccurate. My custom class is a subclass of NSObject, and has NSMutableArray, int, NSString, BOOL & NSDate as properties.

Comment: I've got a problem very similar to this. How would I go about saving an object with an NSArray of custom objects declared inside it?

Comment: @Charl: Hi Charl did you solve this issue. I am getting same problem. Can you suggest me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just implement the encoding and decoding methods in your custom class. That will do. Some sample,

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pageNumber] forKey:@"pageNumber"];
    [encoder encodeObject:path forKey:@"path"];
    [encoder encodeObject:array forKey:@"array"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super init]) 
    {
        self.pageNumber = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"pageNumber"] intValue];
        self.path = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"path"];
        self.array = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    }
}
```

You can see totally three data types being encoded and decoded - int, string, array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi cocoakomali! Thank you for your response. What I don't understand is, if it's possible to encode an array as you have done in the above example, why can I not just do the encoding with one line of code on my mainObjectArray?

Comment: Since your mainObjectArray is made from a custom class, you should implement the methods as I did.

Comment: I've got a problem very similar to this. How would I go about saving an object with an NSArray of custom objects declared inside it?

Comment: what should `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder  return

Comment: return self for the initWithCoder